# How to mirror this section of hair horizontally, so that it does not flip upside down and can be applied to the other side of the head?

Tags: modeling, mirror

[image: n/a]

How to mirror this section of hair horizontally, so that it does not flip upside down and can be applied to the other side of the head?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to select girl mesh. SHIFT+S>Cursor to selected.Switch Pivot point to 3D Cursor and then S, X, -1 to mirror hair on the X axis.